# how to use ListView class for two different templates

Tags: python, django, templates

I have a `ListView` class in `view.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views import generic

from entertainment.models import Entertainmentblog

class ListView(generic.ListView):
      template_name = 'entertainment/index.html'
      context_object_name = 'latest_article_list'
      slug = None
      id = None

def get_queryset(self):

      return Entertainmentblog.objects.order_by('-posted')[:25]

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
      model = Entertainmentblog
      template_name = 'entertainment/article.html'
```

and I'm using this view to display a list of articles in `index.html`.But,I would like to show the same list of articles in `article.html` after the article.I have used the blocks correctly but,it won't show any articles because in `ListView`the template name is index.html.How do I solve this?

Comment: You could add extra context (template name in this case) in url router and work for switch in CBV. More info here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/class-based-views/#making-friendly-template-contexts

Comment: But,article.html already has a view DetailView .How do I make changes to that to include the article list from ListView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Mixin:

```
class LatestArticleMixin(object):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(LatestArticleMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        try:
            context['latest_article_list'] = Entertainmentblog.objects.order_by('-posted')[:25]
        except:
            pass
        return context
```

Then refactor your DetailView:

```
class DetailView(LatestArticleMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = Entertainmentblog
    template_name = 'entertainment/article.html'
```

In your template if there are articles:

```
{% if latest_article_list %}
    ....

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score -1):

In `urls.py` you can set `template_name` as attribute to `ListView` url entry router.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^a/$', ListView.as_view(model=Poll, template_name="a.html")),
    (r'^b/$', ListView.as_view(model=Poll, template_name="b.html")),
)
```

In `views.py` even you don't need to set template.

**views.py**

```
class ListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Poll
```